# Contact form not using ajax properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I had a normal php contact form sample which I modified to suit my needs. I then wanted to use ajax to post to my php mail script. For some reason, I still still see the post values in my url like this:

`http://www.example.com?name=bruno&email=bruno%40gmail.com&subject=ajax+test+ff&message=test`

I am also failing at getting a proper response from my php as to whether the send was successful or not. I would like to display a message if successful.

The email however sends.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="4"></textarea>
    <button id="submit" class="form-control text-uppercase">Send</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(){
         var data = {
         name:$("#name").val(),
         email:$("#email").val(),
         subject:$("#subject").val(),
         message:$("#message").val(),
      }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sendmail.php",
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
            })
            .success(function(response) {
                if(!response.errors && response.result=="success") {
                alert("success")
                } else 
                if(!response.errors && response.result=="oops") {
                alert("oops somethign went wrong");
                }
            });
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $inputvalues = $_POST;
    $errors = false;
    $result = false;

    $email_to = "bruno@example.com";
    $email_from = "info@example.com";
    $name = $inputvalues["name"];
    $email = $inputvalues["email"];
    $message = $inputvalues["message"];
    $email_subject = $inputvalues["subject"];
    $headers = "From: " . $email_from . "\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email . "\n";
    $message = "Name: ". $name . "\r\nMessage: " . $message;
    ini_set("sendmail_from", $email_from);
    $sent = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers, "-f" .$email);
    if ($sent) {
       $returnResult = "success";
    } 
    else {
        $returnResult = "oops";
    }
       echo json_encode(['result' => $returnResult, 'errors' => $errors]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the form from being submitted in your listener, i.e.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         var data = {
         // etc.
```

Comment: Ah! That sorted out the ajax issues. Thanks so much Chris!